# Get Date Field of Current List Item and compare it with current date (todays date)?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I want on EditForm to execute javascript to compare the field "Start Date" with the current date. In case the current date >= start date to make a field read only.

How can i get the value of a field of current item and then compare it with current date?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it a custom form you are creating using SPD?

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
var startDate = document.queryAllSelector("input[title='Start Date']")[0];
var startdateValue = new Date(startDate.value);
var today = new Date();
if(today >= startdateValue)
{
  startDate.readOnly = true;
}
```